# How to create encoded primary key for table from two different table primary keys

Tags: postgresql

I have two table Table 1 and Table 2 now I have to create thrid table whose primary key is encoded and combination of table1 and table 2 pk's. I also want to fetch the record of table3 with table 1 and table 2 on the basis of table 3 pk.

can some one help me.

solution   in my mind was if I can create some thing similar to JWT toke from the table 1 and table 2 pk's and store it in table 3 pk. but the problems is how I will decode it and perform basic CRUD operation with join query between different tables

Comment: What is wrong with a compound key of both?

Comment: I want to hide that information

Comment: @WasimKhan Hide what from whom, from your database? Bad idea. You can't join on the encoded form.